# Receiving error within Smartthings Device Handler

Tags: groovy, smartthings

I am receiving the below error when trying to compile the device_handler code for the Sylvania Smart+ Plug. The code comes from https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71PrgM-PamL.pdf

The error:

Org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: script_dth_metadata_0631e407_ffd8_4ceb_b49a_877fd47635df: 94: expecting ''', found '\r' @ line 94, column 55. nalResult.value == "on" ? '{{ ^ 1 error

Line 94:
def descriptionText = finalResult.value == "on" ? '{{

```js
metadata {
definition (name: "SYLVANIA Smart Plug", namespace: "ledvanceDH", author: 
"Ledvance") {
capability "Actuator"
capability "Switch"
capability "Power Meter"
capability "Configuration"
capability "Refresh"
capability "Sensor"
capability "Health Check"
fingerprint profileId: "C05E", inClusters: 
"1000,0000,0003,0004,0005,0006,0B04,FC0F", outClusters: "0019", manufacturer: "OSRAM", 
model: "Plug 01", deviceJoinName: "SYLVANIA Smart Plug"
fingerprint profileId: "0104", inClusters: 
"0000,0003,0004,0005,0006,0B05,FC01,FC08", outClusters: "0003,0019", manufacturer: 
"LEDVACE", model: "PLUG", deviceJoinName: "SYLVANIA Smart Plug"
}
// simulator metadata
simulator {
// status messages
status "on": "on/off: 1"
status "off": "on/off: 0"
// reply messages
reply "zcl on-off on": "on/off: 1"
reply "zcl on-off off": "on/off: 0"
}
preferences {
section {
image(name: 'educationalcontent', multiple: true, images: [
"http://cdn.devicegse.smartthings.com/Outlet/US/OutletUS1.jpg",
"http://cdn.devicegse.smartthings.com/Outlet/US/OutletUS2.jpg"
])
}
}
// UI tile definitions
tiles(scale: 2) {
multiAttributeTile(name:"switch", type: "lighting", width: 6, height: 4, 
canChangeIcon: true){
tileAttribute ("device.switch", key: "PRIMARY_CONTROL") {
attributeState "on", label: 'On', action: "switch.off", 
icon: "st.Appliances.appliances17", backgroundColor: "#79b821", nextState: "turningOff"
attributeState "off", label: 'Off', action: "switch.on", 
icon: "st.Appliances.appliances17", backgroundColor: "#565C51", nextState: "turningOn"
attributeState "turningOn", label: 'Turning On', action: 
"switch.off", icon: "st.Appliances.appliances17", backgroundColor: "#60903A", nextState: 
"turningOff"
attributeState "turningOff", label: 'Turning Off', action: 
"switch.on", icon: "st.Appliances.appliances17", backgroundColor: "#CACACA", nextState: 
"turningOn"
}
tileAttribute ("power", key: "SECONDARY_CONTROL") {
attributeState "power", label:'${currentValue} W'
}
}
standardTile("refresh", "device.power", inactiveLabel: false, decoration: 
"flat", width: 2, height: 2) {
state "default", label:'', action:"refresh.refresh", 
icon:"st.secondary.refresh"
}
main "switch"
details(["switch","refresh"])
}
}
// Parse incoming device messages to generate events
def parse(String description) {
log.debug "description is $description"
def finalResult = zigbee.getKnownDescription(description)
def event = [:]
//TODO: Remove this after getKnownDescription can parse it automatically
if (!finalResult && description!="updated")
finalResult = 
getPowerDescription(zigbee.parseDescriptionAsMap(description))
if (finalResult) {
log.info "final result = $finalResult"
if (finalResult.type == "update") {
log.info "$device updates: ${finalResult.value}"
event = null
}
else if (finalResult.type == "power") {
def powerValue = (finalResult.value as Integer)/10
event = createEvent(name: "power", value: powerValue, 
descriptionText: '{{ device.displayName }} power is {{ value }} Watts', translatable: 
true)
/*
Dividing by 10 as the Divisor is 10000 and unit is kW for 
the device. AttrId: 0302 and 0300. Simplifying to 10
power level is an integer. The exact power level with 
correct units needs to be handled in the device type
to account for the different Divisor value (AttrId: 0302) 
and POWER Unit (AttrId: 0300). CLUSTER for simple metering is 0702
*/
}
else {
def descriptionText = finalResult.value == "on" ? '{{ 
device.displayName }} is On' : '{{ device.displayName }} is Off'
event = createEvent(name: finalResult.type, value: 
finalResult.value, descriptionText: descriptionText, translatable: true)
}
}
else {
def cluster = zigbee.parse(description)
if (cluster && cluster.clusterId == 0x0006 && cluster.command == 0x07){
if (cluster.data[0] == 0x00) {
log.debug "ON/OFF REPORTING CONFIG RESPONSE: " + cluster
event = createEvent(name: "checkInterval", value: 60 * 12, 
displayed: false, data: [protocol: "zigbee", hubHardwareId: device.hub.hardwareID])
}
else {
log.warn "ON/OFF REPORTING CONFIG FAILED- error 
code:${cluster.data[0]}"
event = null
}
}
else {
log.warn "DID NOT PARSE MESSAGE for description : $description"
log.debug "${cluster}"
}
}
return event
}
def off() {
zigbee.off()
}
def on() {
zigbee.on()
}
/**
* PING is used by Device-Watch in attempt to reach the Device
* */
def ping() {
return zigbee.onOffRefresh()
}
def refresh() {
zigbee.onOffRefresh() + zigbee.electricMeasurementPowerRefresh()
}
def configure() {
// Device-Watch allows 2 check-in misses from device + ping (plus 1 min lag time)
// enrolls with default periodic reporting until newer 5 min interval is confirmed
sendEvent(name: "checkInterval", value: 2 * 10 * 60 + 1 * 60, displayed: false, 
data: [protocol: "zigbee", hubHardwareId: device.hub.hardwareID])
// OnOff minReportTime 0 seconds, maxReportTime 5 min. Reporting interval if no 
activity
refresh() + zigbee.onOffConfig(0, 300) + powerConfig()
}
//power config for devices with min reporting interval as 1 seconds and reporting 
interval if no activity as 10min (600s)
//min change in value is 01
def powerConfig() {
[
"zdo bind 0x${device.deviceNetworkId} 1 ${endpointId} 0x0B04 
{${device.zigbeeId}} {}", "delay 2000",
"zcl global send-me-a-report 0x0B04 0x050B 0x29 1 600 {05 00}",
//The send-me-a-report is custom to the attribute type for CentraLite
"delay 200",
"send 0x${device.deviceNetworkId} 1 ${endpointId}", "delay 2000"
]
}
private getEndpointId() {
new BigInteger(device.endpointId, 16).toString()
}
//TODO: Remove this after getKnownDescription can parse it automatically
def getPowerDescription(descMap) {
def powerValue = "undefined"
if (descMap.cluster == "0B04") {
if (descMap.attrId == "050b") {
if(descMap.value!="ffff")
powerValue = zigbee.convertHexToInt(descMap.value)
}
}
else if (descMap.clusterId == "0B04") {
if(descMap.command=="07"){
return [type: "update", value : "power (0B04) capability configured 
successfully"]
}
}
if (powerValue != "undefined"){
return [type: "power", value : powerValue]
}
else {
return [:]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought of it sooner... The problem is with the copy/paste. The long lines were broken by a "return". I removed the returns and the script compiled.